# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarmor_runtime_000000'

Tags: python, fastapi, pyarmor

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQuMj.png)Hi there, im struggling while obfuscation Fastapi project with pyarmor.
> It show ModuleNotFoundError and dont know what to do.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vl6e.png)
>
> Here is the body of the error:

`INFO:     Started reloader process [11972] using watchgod Process SpawnProcess-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap     self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started     target(sockets=sockets)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 68, in run     return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run     return loop.run_until_complete(main)   File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in serve     config.load()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 448, in load     self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string     raise exc from None`your text   `File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string     module = importlib.import_module(module_str)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed   File "/home/israilovk/repositories/loan_monitoring/./dist/app/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>     from pyarmor_runtime_000000 import __pyarmor__ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarmor_runtime_000000'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy all the contents of the dist/ folder (or the custom output folder you used in your commandline) into your runtime folder/machine. Copying just the script you obfuscated does not work